SSIS Serialized OnError Tasks logging error on SQL Server and sending email
I do have a quite big project in SSIS, with multiple packages, and some MASTER packages using them.
I want to find the best method to log errors, and send an email on failure.
For that here are some of my constraints :

Log errors on SQL Server
Send an email with information corresponding to the package name and the error description
Serialize the email part, not having to modify this email task in all my packages by hand

To do that, I thought about creating a package part, with a C# script where I send the email.
My biggest problem is to retrieve the ErrorDescription.
I tried the followings :

Get the variable ErrorDescription in the Event Handlers of a package. But when I try to retrive it in the C# script of the Email package part, I can't do it (string ErrorDesc = Dts.Variables["$User::ErrorDescription"].Value.ToString())
Get the last rows of the table dbo.sysssislog with a SQL task before my C# script, registering the result in a variable. But since I use a Project Connection Manager I need to encrypt the package part like the rest of the project (EncryptSensitiveWithPassword), and then I can't access to the variable of my project Dts.Variables["$Project::SMTP_Credential_Users"].Value.ToString() (which I could access with an email package part not encrypted.

What recommendation do you have in order to log errors and send emails with error content in a serializable way ?
